# pycuda installation error on ubuntu: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pycuda

I am beginner and installing pycuda2011.2.2 on ubuntu 11.10, but can't complete it. Cuda is 4.0.

I have installed libraries:

> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools
>   libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev -y

calling configure.py like this:

> $ ./configure.py --cuda-root=/usr/local/cuda
>   --cudadrv-lib-dir=/usr/lib --boost-inc-dir=/usr/include --boost-lib-dir=/usr/lib --boost-python-libname=boost_python-mt-py27 --boost-thread-libname=boost_thread-mt

But, When i do:

```
.....@ubuntu:~/pycuda-2011.2.2$ make -j 4
```

I get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
>
> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcurand.so when searching
>   for -lcurand

why this error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `LDFLAGS` environment variable so that the *pycuda* setup can find `libcuda.so`, which on ubuntu systems is in a non-standard location (`/usr/lib/nvidia-current`).

The installation of *pycuda 2012.1* is entirely distutils based, no `Makefile` involved. You install *pycuda* by running `./configure.py` with the appropriate options followed by `LDFLAGS=/usr/lib/nvidia-current python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some newer drivers for the nvidia card, like nvidia-313 (that's what I use), then the file libcuda.so (which is nicknamed lcuda, I don't know why) may not be in the cuda installation directory (which, by default, is /usr/lib/cuda).
Instead, you might have to find it by yourself.
Do:

$ find /usr/lib/*/libcuda.so

for me, the result is

/usr/lib/nvidia-313-updates/libcuda.so

so, when installing pycuda, I do:

$ python configure.py --cuda-root=/usr/lib/nvidia-313-updates

$ make

$ sudo make install

then,

$ optirun python test/test_driver.py

or

$ optirun python some_program_which_imports_pycuda.py

should work fine.